# Fontes não são exibidas quando usado com JSF

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2.2

Criei um projeto Maven que está utilizando JSF2 mais o *framework* do Bootstrap, porém existem umas configurações do Bootstrap que não estão funcionando adequadamente, como vocês podem ver nas figuras abaixo.

Ele está sendo visualizado assim:

[image]

E na verdade era para estar assim:

[image]

Como faço para corrigir esse problema?

Esse é o cabeçalho da pagina para mostra como está configurado para receber as configurações do Bootstrap:

```jsp
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css" />

    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
</h:head>
```

Este é o único trecho da pagina que está apresentando problema;

```jsp
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus.
                    Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit
                    lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in
                    euismod dui</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus.
                    Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit
                    lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in
                    euismod dui</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
                <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus.
                    Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit
                    lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in
                    euismod dui</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

tentei dessa forma, porém não tive sucesso;

```jsp
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

    src: url("#{resource['fonts:glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot]}");
    src: url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix")
        format('embedded-opentype'),
        url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2") format('woff2'),
        url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff") format('woff'),
        url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf") format('truetype'),
        url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular")
        format('svg');
}
```

Essse é a estrutura do meu projeto;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de tudo:

- Você não precisa referenciar bootstrap.css e bootstrap.min.css, utilize apenas o bootstrap.css depois você minifica.
- Dentro do bootstrap.css vai ter algo parecido com isso...

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tente alterar a url dos icones para:

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        src: url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}");
        src: url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
                url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff']}") format('woff'),
                url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf']}") format('truetype'),
                url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg']}#glyphicons-halflingsregular") format('svg');
    }
```

Assim sucessivamente.

Comment: poderia dá uma olhada na minha postagem, acabei de atualizar

Comment: Você tentou modificar seu bloco font-face em bootstrap.css para este da resposta?

Comment: fiz varias tentativas com essa resposta e não tive sucesso, por favor preciso ainda de ajuda.

Comment: cara, vc precisa colocar o diretorio onde está suas fontes... no lugar de:
url("#{resource['fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular...']}
colocar
url("#{resource['resources.fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular...']}

no lugar de fonts/ coloque o diretorio onde está suas fontes.

Comment: baseado na imagem no meu projeto que coloquei na postagem, aonde deve ficar as minhas fontes?

Answer (score 2):

Existem algumas questões

1. Você não pode carregar o bootstrap.js e bootstrap.min.js juntos

   - bootstrap.js é pra desenvolvimento
   - bootstrap.min.js é pra produção

   Aqui:

   ```
       <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
       <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" />
       <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
   ```

   Mude para se for produção:

   ```
       <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
       <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
   ```

   Mude para se for desenvolvimento:

   ```
       <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
       <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
   ```

   Quando carrega o bootstrap.js ele carrega também o .map
2. Com o CSS também, algo como:

   ```
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css" />
   ```

   Se for produção, use somente:

   ```
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
   ```

   Se for desenvolvimento, use somente:

   ```
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.css" />
   ```

   Note que o tema sempre deve vir depois do bootstrap, pra não quebrar a hierarquia.

   O resultado final deve ficar algo como:

   - Se for ambiente de desenvolvimento:

     ```
     <h:head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
         <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
         <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.css" />

         <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
         <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" />
     </h:head>
     ```
   - Se for ambiente de produção:

     ```
     <h:head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
         <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css" />
         <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

         <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
         <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
     </h:head>
     ```
3. Acredito que este seja o teu problema (note que os anteriores podem refletir neste problema, principalmente por causa do uso do tema), detalhando a resposta do [@rafaelblink](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81153/3635):

   - `#{resource['fonts:glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot]}` por exemplo você abre o apostrofo `'`, mas não o fecha.
   - `?#iefix` você usou ? dentro de resource e não fechou o o `{[` quando deveria com `]}`, note que `?` e `#` devem ir depois de `]}` pois não fazem parte do "caminho real" do resource.

   O código deve ficar assim:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
       src: url("#{resource['fonts:glyphiconshalflings-regular.eot']}");
       src: url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot']}?#iefix")
           format('embedded-opentype'),
           url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2']}") format('woff2'),
           url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff']}") format('woff'),
           url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf']}") format('truetype'),
           url("#{resource['fonts:glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg']}#glyphicons_halflingsregular")
           format('svg');
   }
   ```

   Se falhar, siga o que recomendei aqui (Não edite os arquivos originais): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82225/3635

   Crie um arquivo chamado *main.css* e adicione o `@font-face {...}` nele.