# Como alterar a tag Jumbotron no bootstrap no navegador google chrome?

Tags: jsf-2.2, bootstrap-3

Observem com atenção a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora dá uma olhada no código

```
<!-- jumbotron-->

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>JWB Tecnologia</h1>
        <p>Este portal foi criado para auxiliar as empresas e
            profissionais que buscam informações sobre Sistemas ERP. Para
            ajudá-lo em sua pesquisa, selecionamos as principais informações
            sobre Sistema ERP para que esta ferramenta possa contribuir ao
            máximo para a melhoria da qualidade de seus serviços e a
            competitividade de sua empresa.</p>

        <div class="btn-group">

            <h:link styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Download App</h:link>
            <h:link styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-default">Loja Virtual</h:link>
            <h:link styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Lista de ERP</h:link>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End container -->
</div>
<!-- End jumbotron-->
```

Criei um projeto JSF + Maven, ele está corretamente configurado para ter Bootstrap no projeto, sendo que não consigo mudar a cor da tag  Jumbotron como no modelo abaixo;

http://jsfiddle.net/juanmendez/C4Sjg/

esse é meu código no meu arquivo bootstrap.css

```
.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

modifiquei para ficar assim, mas não tive sucesso na pagina

```
.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #ff3600;
    color: white;
}
```

O arquivo que estou tentando alterar é o bootstrap.css, talvez não esteja tendo sucesso por causa de uma bombagem.
A pergunta é;

Como faço para alterar a cor da tag Jumbotron?

***OBS: todos os navegadores tenho o resultado esperado somente não tenho no google chrome***

===========================================================================

Minha pagina

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />

    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />



</h:head>


<style>
body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
</style>

<h:body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">


    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <h:link styleClass="navbar-brand">Quem somos</h:link>

        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Header-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

            <h:link styleClass="btn btn-warning navbar-btn navbar-right">Download agora</h:link>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><h:link>Fotos</h:link></li>
                <li><h:link>Características</h:link></li>
                <li><h:link>Faq</h:link></li>
                <li><h:link>Fale Conosco</h:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Container--> </nav>
    <!-- End navbar -->

    <!-- jumbotron-->

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>JWB Tecnologia</h1>
            <p>Este portal foi criado para auxiliar as empresas e
                profissionais que buscam informações sobre Sistemas ERP. Para
                ajudá-lo em sua pesquisa, selecionamos as principais informações
                sobre Sistema ERP para que esta ferramenta possa contribuir ao
                máximo para a melhoria da qualidade de seus serviços e a
                competitividade de sua empresa.</p>

            <div class="btn-group">

                <h:link styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Download App</h:link>
                <h:link styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-default">Loja Virtual</h:link>
                <h:link styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Lista de ERP</h:link>


            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End container -->
    </div>
    <!-- End jumbotron-->


    <!-- Feedback-->
    <div class="container">
        <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="feedback">
            <h2>
                Frases de Grandes Empresários<small> Leia com atenção</small>
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Seus clientes mais insatisfeitos são sua melhor fonte de
                        aprendizado.</p>
                    <footer>Bill Gates</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Não deixe o barulho da opinião dos outros abafar sua voz
                        interior. E mais importante, tenha a coragem de seguir seu coração
                        e sua intuição. Eles de alguma forma já sabem o que você realmente
                        quer se tornar. Tudo o mais é secundário.</p>
                    <footer>Steve Jobs</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Não deixe o barulho da opinião dos outros abafar sua voz
                        interior. E mais importante, tenha a coragem de seguir seu coração
                        e sua intuição. Eles de alguma forma já sabem o que você realmente
                        quer se tornar. Tudo o mais é secundário.</p>
                    <footer>Mark Zuckerberg - fundados do Facebook</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End row --> </section>
    </div>
    <!--End Container-->


    <!-- call to action -->
    <section>
    <div class="well">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h3>Inscreva-se agora</h3>
            <p>Digite seu nome e e-mail</p>

            <form action="" class="form-inline">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <h:outputLabel value="Nome" />
                    <h:inputText styleClass="form-control" id="subscription" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Email " />
                    <h:inputText styleClass="form-control" id="email" />
                </div>
                <h:button styleClass="btn btn-default" value="Cadastrar" />
            </form>


        </div>
        <!-- end Container-->

    </div>
    <!-- end well--> </section>
    <!-- Call to action -->

    <!-- Gallery -->
    <div class="container">
        <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="galeria">
            <h2>
                Trabalhos Realizados<small> Verifique as Imagens</small>
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel slide" id="screenshot-carousel"
            data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                <!--                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944735/what-is-the-data-target-attribute-in-bootstrap-3 -->

                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="0"
                    class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="highway.jpg" />
                    alt="Text of the image" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Sistema de controle de trafeco</h3>
                        <p>Foi implementado um sistema para o governo do RS</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="river.jpg" />
                    alt="Text of the image" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Sistema Integrado em São Lourenço</h3>
                        <p>Foi para o governo do estado</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="street.jpg" />
                    alt="Text of the image" />

                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Street heading</h3>
                        <p>Sistema para pavimentação privada</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="painting.jpg" />
                    alt="Text of the image" />

                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Ana Paola de Souza Alves</h3>
                        <p>Foi implementado um sistema integrado</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- End Carousel inner -->

            <!--            Não conseguir fazer funcionar isso direito -->

            <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="left carousel-control"
                data-slide="prev"> <span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a> <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="right carousel-control"
                data-slide="next"> <span
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>


        </div>
        <!-- End Carousel --> </section>
    </div>


    <!-- features -->
    <div class="container">
        <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="features">
            <h2>
                Features.<small> Some of the coolest Features of this app.</small>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <!-- End Page Header -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam
                    mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa.
                    Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="imac.jpg"
                    styleClass="img-responsive" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam
                    mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa.
                    Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="smartphone.jpg"
                    styleClass="img-responsive" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam
                    mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa.
                    Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit
                    777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="user.jpg"
                    styleClass="img-responsive" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <p:separator />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                        <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus.
                            Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit
                            lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in
                            euismod dui</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                        <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus.
                            Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit
                            lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in
                            euismod dui</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
                        <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                        <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus.
                            Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit
                            lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in
                            euismod dui</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end row --> </section>
    </div>
    <!-- End Container -->


    <!-- Faq -->

    <div class="container">
        <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="faq">
            <h2>
                FAQ.<small> Engaging with consumers.</small>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <!-- End Page Header -->

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-parent="#accordion"> Question one? </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End panel title -->
                    <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                            consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla.
                            Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Panel collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapse-2" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-parent="#accordion"> Question Two? </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End panel title -->
                    <div id="collapse-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                            consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla.
                            Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Panel collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#collapse-3" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-parent="#accordion"> Question Three? </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End panel title -->
                    <div id="collapse-3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                            consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla.
                            Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Panel collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End panel group --> </section>
    </div>
    <!-- End container -->


    <!-- Footer -->

    <footer>
    <div class="container text-center">


        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com">YouTube</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p>&copy; Copyright @ 2015 Desenvolvido por Wladimir</p>

    </div>
    <!-- end Container--> </footer>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</h:body>

</html>
```

meu projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o problema aqui seja parte do que citei nesta pergunta:

- [Fontes não são exibidas quando usado com JSF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82216/3635)

  1. Você não pode carregar o bootstrap.js e bootstrap.min.js juntos

     - bootstrap.js é pra desenvolvimento
     - bootstrap.min.js é pra produção

  Aqui:

  ```
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" />
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
  ```

  Mude para se for produção:

  ```
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
  ```

  Mude para se for desenvolvimento:

  ```
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
  ```

  Quando carrega o bootstrap.js ele carrega também o .map

  2. Com o CSS também, algo como:

  Se for produção, use somente:

  ```
   <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css" />
   <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  ```

  Se for desenvolvimento, use somente:

  ```
   <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
   <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.css" />
  ```

Note que o **tema** sempre deve vir depois do bootstrap, pra não quebrar a hierarquia.

### Não edite os arquivos originais

Ao invés de modificar os arquivos do bootstrap, que ao meu ver é uma péssima pratica pois pode conflitar com updates futuros, você deve criar um .css a parte e ele deve vir depois dos demais, deve ficar assim:

- Ambiente de desenvolvimento:

  ```
  <h:head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.css" />
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css" /> <!-- Seu arquivo customizavel -->

      <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" />
  </h:head>
  ```
- Ambiente de produção:

  ```
  <h:head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css" />
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
      <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css" /> <!-- Seu arquivo customizavel -->

      <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
      <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
  </h:head>
  ```

Neste arquivo main.css adicione:

```
.jumbotron {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

### Ambiente de desenvolvimento

É o ambiente usado apenas para a criação, desenvolvimento e testes do software criado ou mantido por você ou por uma equipe.

### Ambiente de produção

É o ambiente usado apenas para gerar a produção ou o trabalho que o software deve realizar, por exemplo se for um software de fluxo de caixa usado em uma rede (interna ou externa) quando o usuário o usa é o que chamamos de "produção". Neste ambiente geralmente (preferencialmente) não fazemos atualizações, manutenções e testes diretamente no software, já que isto pode afetar o funcionamento, para isto usamos o **ambiente de desenvolvimento** e depois de tudo corrigido (geralmente) colocamos o servidor em modo de manutenção ou "leitura" e então você deve subir os arquivos.

### Arquivos .min

Os arquivos .min.js e .min.css são usados somente (geralmente) no ambiente de produção, é uma versão compactada do CSS e JS originais.

No ambiente de desenvolvimento usamos apenas o .js e o .css (sem .min).

Comment: muito obrigado por me informa, mas o problema persisti.

Comment: @wladyband mesmo com criando um main.css? Você editou muito o arquivo bootstrap.css?

Comment: eu somente alterei aquela parte do código do bootstrap.

Comment: @wladyband Faça backup da pasta css, apague tudo que tiver haver com bootstrap da pasta, baixe o bootstrap limpo (sem edições) e copie o bootstrap.css e bootstrap-theme.css "limpos" na pasta CSS, após isto crie o arquivo main.css e coloque ele nesta ordem: `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css" />`. Então edite apenas o main.css.

Comment: @wladyband Editei a resposta, nela agora tem o código de como deve chamar o main.css e a ordem que deve ficar os .css, espero que ajude.

Comment: nossa cara, muito obrigado pegou, está funcionando certinho, valeu mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendi direito se esse bootstrap que vc tá alterando é o que vc criou ou é o css do thema do bootstrap..

Mas para alterar existem tres maneiras:

1 - na hierarquia dos seletores (ex. `#SeletorPai .jumbotron {}`);

2 - na hierarquia dos arquivos (ex. chamar o arquivo `bootstrap.css` depois de todos os outros arquivos css);

3 - ou colocar a tag !important ampos o propriedade (ex.  `background-color: #ff3600 !important;` )

Uma dica é manter o padrão do documento.. se vc tá usando o nome da cor, continua usando o nome, se tá o usando os hexadecimal, usa somente os hex (substitui whit por #fff)